# RxJava combining observables and comparing against previous values

Tags: rx-java

I'm trying to figure out the best way to combine different types of observables in a sequential order and then compare results. Looking at zip and combineLatest, I don't think they are the right fit. How can I do the following?

```
@Test
    public void shouldInsertRecord(){



        BidsEntity bid = new BidsEntity(/* omitted */);


        Observable<Integer> count1 = bidsRepository.getBid(bid.getUserId(), bid.getListingId()).count();

        Observable<Boolean> insert = bidsRepository.insertBid(bid);

        Observable<Integer> count2 = bidsRepository.getBid(bid.getUserId(), bid.getListingId()).count();


        //run count1, run insert, run count2 in that order
        //assert that count2 is greater than count1 

    }
```

Comment: Your code has a lot of unrelated stuff. It is also not clear what sequence you expect as a result of combination. Instead you could simply provide input sequence examples and expected combined output sequence.

Comment: Hi @yurgis, I'm not sure what is unrelated - I'm attempting to do three operations and compare the results of operation 1 and operation 3.

Comment: Ok I just noticed you seem like running a unit test not a production code. In that case you just apply toBlocking().singleOrDefault() to all 3 observables. It is perfectly fine to use blocking in a test code. Another option you have is using CountDownLatch set to 3 before your async calls, call countDown in onNext for all 3 observable and capture the values in AtomicIntegers and AtomicBoolean. After async calls, have latch.await() that will block until all values arrive to your atomic vars.

Answer (score 0):

Not being sequential (aka blocking) is kind of the point of ReactiveX.

Looking at your example I think having a single observable that emits values whenever a Bid is inserted would be reasonable. Then you subscribe to that observable and do whatever it is you want to do with the information in a single observer.

You already have a setup that looks fit for it. Make `bidsRepository.getBid(...)` return the observable that emits whenever a new Bid has been added and replace the `count` variables with a single observer.

Comment: You are correct that nonblocking is the point, but there has to be some way of guaranteeing order for a test like this. I'm not sure how I could make the Repo emit when a new bid has been added as this is largely a shell over sql. I'll think on it.

Comment: I obviously don't know the specifics of your repo, but Subjects might be something you want to look into: https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%201%20-%20Getting%20Started/2.%20Key%20types.md#subject